# Redirects instead of changing text and posting

Tags: javascript, redirect, post, roblox

I'm attempting to make an **automatic** forum bump bot using the console on ROBLOX. (it regards the wait time between posts) I enter the ID of the forum as a parameter, and every 30 seconds it should bump the thread, editing the TextArea to the second parameter and clicking the "Post" button.

I'm having huge troubles, mainly because I am a JavaScript noobie. I don't know how to finish what I started.

Here is the code, instead of doing what I want it just redirects to the Forum page to reply, but doesn't do anything else. Thank you for all help, I really appreciate it.

```
 function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; 
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

function bump(id) {
console.log("bumping")
window.setInterval(function () {
    post('/Forum/AddPost.aspx?PostID=' + id + '&mode=flat', {ctl00_cphRoblox_Createeditpost1_PostForm_PostBody: 'whatttt'});
    }, 20000);
}
bump(159628387);
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me for not just commenting, but I don't have the rep for that yet...

As someone who runs their own forum, I would say, "please don't."  No one likes bots, and while they're useful for things like analytics and crawling, posting on forums is just annoying, unhelpful, and usually an instant ban.

As a JavaScript dev, I would ask how you're trying to do this?  Is it just code that you put into your console?

Console code, and JavaScript in particular, is scoped to the page you're on.  If the page redirects, everything that was running is no longer running.  Even if you're putting this into something like a Chrome Extension, every time the extension is activated it's going to run the code for that page and then automatically stop as soon as you navigate anywhere, and give you a blank slate for the freshly loaded page.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Console. The bot is practical because this is the most active forum. Thanks for the concern, though.

Comment: I absolutely agree, especially for this specific type of bot. You might even get banned for a bump bot. Bump it yourself if you absolutely must, even then it may be frowned upon.

Comment: Guys, the reason I use it is because in literally 10 seconds my post will be off the page. It's the most active forum there, and it's not like I'm bumping it every second. I just want fixing.

Comment: The Chrome Console, and injected JavaScript in general, is locked into a single page scope to prevent abuse.  If it wasn't this way, you could theoretically use JavaScript to make a spam-bot in less than ten minutes, or use Chrome to send information from future pages that the user navigates.  If you're that insistent on spamming, you'll have to look into automation, something like Selenium, Coded UI, Water, or the like.